# How to find and delete folders that are empty / contains empty folders only

Tags: python

If folder X is empty, I would like to delete X.

If folder Y only contains folder X and other folders that are empty, I would like to delete Y.

If folder Z only contains folders like X and/or Y, I would like to delete Z.

How do I do this recursively for anything under a specific dir, with Python?

I tried something like the following, but it is only able to identify folders like X, not folders like Y or Z.

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = '/home/abc'
for path in Path(folder).glob("**/*"):
    if path.is_dir() and len(list(path.iterdir())) == 0:
        logger.info(f"remove {path}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a bit verbose, but this seems to do the job.

```
def dir_empty(path):
    empty = True
    for item in path.glob('*'):
        if item.is_file():
            empty = False
        if item.is_dir() and not dir_empty(item):
            empty = False
    if empty:
        path.rmdir()  # Remove if you just want to have the result
    return empty

from pathlib import Path
dir_empty(Path('Z'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.rmdir()` will fail on any directory with contents.  So one method here is to just rmdir every directory from bottom to top while suppressing the `OSError` exception which is thrown when attempting to remove a non-empty directory.  All empty ones will be removed, all with contents will remain.  Technically, checking if a directory is empty before attempting the removal is a race condition (though typically, a harmless one).

Let's take this filesystem with 2 files in it.

```
testtree/
├── a
│   └── aa
│       └── filea
├── b
│   ├── bb
│   └── fileb
└── c
    └── cc
```

And run this:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
from contextlib import suppress

for root,dirs,_ in os.walk("testtree", topdown=False):
    for d in dirs:
        with suppress(OSError):
            os.rmdir(Path(root,d))
```

Then the tree is transformed to

```
testtree/
├── a
│   └── aa
│       └── filea
└── b
    └── fileb
```

bb, cc, and c were all removed.

Comment: thank you! I believe this also works for my case

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `glob("**/*")` appears to do a preorder traversal. In other words, it returns a parent folder before returning any children.

You need to do a postorder traversal instead. In your example, if you delete a folder like X, then Y just becomes the same as X.

You could do this with manual recursion. But if you want to use `glob()`, you need to reverse the items returned. You can do this with `reversed(Path(folder.glob("**/*"))`.

Comment: Using `os.walk()` instead of `glob()` would allow the traversal to proceed in a non-top-down manner.